# How do you collect data for a specific input element in python?

Tags: python, list, find, iteration, element

so i have this data on a text file called data.txt

```
P005 NY 18/05/2021 23 40
P011 HK 16/05/2021 23 33
P023 TK 15/05/2021 24 41
P023 TK 15/05/2021 20 30
```

the first column is weather station code, the second is station initials, third is date, fourth is temperature and fifth is rainfall. (mind you the columns have no headers)

I import this text and store them in five lists.

Then i ask the user to imput the weather station code to i can output the data colleted from that station. WHICH IS WHERE I GET STUCK

Specifically for example if the user imputs P023 my output should be

```
TK 15/05/2021 24 41
TK 15/05/2021 20 30
```

I need help so i can get my output correct. my attempt is below.

```
infile = open("data.txt",'r') 
assert isinstance(infile, object)
data = infile.read()
infile.close()
lines = data.split("\n")   

Station_ID = []
Station_Name = []
Date_Time = []
Temperature = []
Rainfall = []


for line in lines:         
               
    record = line.split( )
    Station_ID.append((record[0]))
    Station_Name.append(record[1])
    Date_Time.append(record[2])
    Temperature.append(record[3])
    Rainfall.append(record[4])
    

loop= True
while loop:         
    
    Choice = input("Press 1 to enter code")
     
    if Choice==1:
    
        RequestID = input("Enter valid Weather Station ID Code: ")

        # it is at this point where i have no clue what i have to do
                if RequestID in Station_ID:
                print (index, (value1, value2, value3, value4,) in enumerate(zip(Station_Name, Date_Time, Temperature, Rainfall))
                    
        
    elif choice%=2:
        print ("you will now exit")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

since you are already storing those details as a list, the index of the Station_ID can be used to find the required details,

```
if RequestID in Station_ID:
                 indx=Station_ID.index(RequestID)
                 print(Station_Name[indx],Date_Time[indx],Temperature[indx],Rainfall[indx])
```

Comment: Thanks SK. I've flagged you're answer as a useful answer so that SO will add credits to you. It'l show once i reach 15 reps...thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you really want to achieve, but you can try the following if it fits your need:

```
from collections import defaultdict

with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
   data = f.readlines()

data_dict = defaultdict(list)
for line in data:
    l = line.split()
    data_dict[l[0]].append(' '.join(l[1:]))

search_info = input("Provide station ID: ")
for station_ID, infos in data_dict.items():  
    if  station_ID == search_info:
        print(infos)
```

output:

```
Provide station ID: P023
['TK 15/05/2021 24 41', 'TK 15/05/2021 20 30']
```

Comment: @BuzzKotta You are welcome bro. And please don't forget to mark it  if it fits your need.

Comment: i tried casting the vote for your answer but the message says I have to have 15 reputations to do that.

Comment: R. Marolahy. could you help me with one last code. I need a line that gives me details of the station that gives the highest temperature (details like date and station name). I also need to adjust that code to give me highest rainfall

Comment: @BuzzKotta You can always mark it as accepted answer but you can't still upvote it.

Comment: I don't understand well what you want to achieve.  Is it for  all stations or just for the searched stations that you want to show the details infos of the one with the max temperature?

Comment: sorry i meant for all stations....PS i also green ticked your answer

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use the [defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) from collections modules, where the default is a list:

```
from collections import defaultdict
data_dict = defaultdict(list)
```

And store the data there:

```
infile = open("data.txt",'r') 
assert isinstance(infile, object)
data = infile.read()
infile.close()
lines = data.split("\n")

for line in lines:         
    record = line.split( )
    station, rest = record[0], record[1:]
    data_dict[station].append(rest)
```

So you end up with a structure like this for `data_dict`:

```
defaultdict(list,
            {'P005': [['NY', '18/05/2021', '23', '40']],
             'P011': [['HK', '16/05/2021', '23', '33']],
             'P023': [['TK', '15/05/2021', '24', '41'],
              ['TK', '15/05/2021', '20', '30']]})
```

Then you can access the data by key station:

```
data_dict['P023']
#=> [['TK', '15/05/2021', '24', '41'], ['TK', '15/05/2021', '20', '30']]
```

Answer (score 0):

The folling one should work, at least for this case

```
import numpy as np
path = 'yourpath\data.txt'


infile = open(path,'r') 
assert isinstance(infile, object)
data = infile.read()
infile.close()
lines = data.split("\n")   

Station_ID = []
Station_Name = []
Date_Time = []
Temperature = []
Rainfall = []


for line in lines:         
               
    record = line.split( )
    Station_ID.append((record[0]))
    Station_Name.append(record[1])
    Date_Time.append(record[2])
    Temperature.append(record[3])
    Rainfall.append(record[4])
    
result=[];

Choice = input("Press 1 to enter code: ")
     
if int(Choice) == 1:
    
    RequestID = input("Enter valid Weather Station ID Code: ")
    
    # it is at this point where i have no clue what i have to do
    
    for i in range(len(Station_ID)):
        
        if RequestID == Station_ID[i]:
            result=np.append(result, [Station_Name[i]+' '+Date_Time[i]+' '+Temperature[i]+' '+Rainfall[i]])
    
    print(result)

else:
    print ("you will now exit")
```